# How to insert date to the web path api

Tags: json, excel

I have loaded some data from web api using Excel power query using steps described under this link:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-a-json-file-f65207ab-d957-4bf0-bec3-a08bb53cd4c0

I was trying this solution:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd
Point 4. says *"In the Connection Properties dialog box, click the Definition tab, and then click Parameters"*. Unfortunately "properties" button is disabled in my case.

My source looks like this:
Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2013-10-01&end=2019-08-14&currency=EUR"))

I would like to get results with the end=today. Is it possible to do it somehow by getting current date directly in the query or via parameter connected to any cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use end date out of scale, you will get data from start to current day, ie.
https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2013-10-01&currency=EUR&end=2020-01-01